# Android Studio: binary files getting corrupted when checked into CVS

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, cvs

When checking in my Android Project in CVS via the Android Studio GUI, something bad happens: Android Studio seems to fail to flag binary files as such, which causes these files (such as images) to be corrupted during the check-in. CVS treat them as text and does some kind of ASCII conversion.

When I try to make my project after this, it gives error messages like these:

```
AAPT err(955175397): libpng error: PNG file corrupted by ASCII conversion
```

In Eclipse I'm used to seeing a pop-up when checking in an "unknown" file extension into CVS, allowing me to specify whether it is text or binary.

Is there such an option in Android Studio? And if not, how can I fix this problem, preferably without having to use `cvs` from  the command line?

Comment: How does an ascii converted png file look like?

Comment: It's corrupted, so you can't open it.

Comment: You already told that. It's no answer to my question though. One can open all files in WordPad or a hex editor to compare. And if it is converted to ascii you can open it in any plain text editer. So how does it look like then?

Comment: @greenapps I already restored them. What information are you expecting to get from this? In Eclipse, I always got a pop-up when I was checking in a new type extension, asking me to specify whether it was binary or text. I believe that simply is the problem: Android Studio doesn't ask me and checks everything in as text.

Comment: If you've not seen, the CVS help pages [Handling Binary files](http://cvsgui.sourceforge.net/howto/cvsdoc/cvs_9.html#SEC80) and [csvwrappers](http://cvsgui.sourceforge.net/howto/cvsdoc/cvs_18.html#SEC162) might help, but I don't know how that info would fit into Android Studio

Comment: How you solved your problem

Comment: @rajahsekar The problem is caused by keyword expansion and line ending conversion that CVS does on text files. The links provided by TripeHound were very useful. You can check them in using the command line with the `-kb` option which prevents CVS from doing that. However, I found this too much of a hassle, so personally I just reverted to using Git, even though my company uses CVS for everything.

Comment: Okay Thank you i will check